# Erro:Edge vector must be monotonically non-decreasing

Tags: matlab, function, histogram, montecarlo

My issue is with MCsolutionupdated() function in that I am unable to run it for 20,000+ iterations as I obtain the error "Edge vector must be monotonically non-decreasing.". Sometimes, I even obtain Inf elements (when I do not get this error) for final_matrix which does not make sense either. When I run Nielsennewupdated(casechoice, no_iterations) I am able to run it for as many simulations and I do not ever obtain Inf elements. So, I think there must be a problem with MCsolutionupdated().

```
function [final_matrix, thresh_strain] = MCsolutionupdated()

no_iterations = input('No. of iterations?:');

thresh_strain = zeros(1,no_iterations*16);

casechoice =input('Enter 1 for 1st Layup and 2 for 2nd layup:');

 J = Nielsennewupdated(casechoice, no_iterations);
 thresh_strain = J;


roundedValues = round(thresh_strain/.0001)*0.0001;
myUniqueValues = unique(roundedValues);
i = numel(myUniqueValues);
nelements  = hist(thresh_strain(:),myUniqueValues); 

for i=1:i
    percent(i)  = (nelements(1,i)/numel(thresh_strain))*100;
end

final_matrix = [myUniqueValues' percent'];

% uniqueValues,~,uniqueIndex] = unique(ans);
% frequency = accumarray(uniqueIndex(:),1)./numel(ans);

header = {'Threshold Strain' 'Probability of occurrence'};
xlswrite('results.xlsx', header) 
xlswrite('results.xlsx', final_matrix,'A2')
```

Thanks

Comment: Please post the entire error message with line numbers so we can see where it occurs. Have you done any sort of debugging? Does the error occur before `Nielsennewupdated` is called, inside of `Nielsennewupdated` or after `Nielsennewupdated` has returned a value? Also there's not need to pre-allocate `thresh_strain` if `Nielsennewupdated` returns that vector (though you might need to pre-allocate in side of `Nielsennewupdated`).

Comment: I think you get the error in `nelements  = hist(thresh_strain(:),myUniqueValues); `. If yes, it means that you cannot have a vector (in your case, `myuniquevalues`) in which values decrease at any point of time. It is surprising though, because, you are using `unique` prior to that, which is going to sort the values in ascending order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is on this line (the error message probably even says as much):

```
nelements  = hist(thresh_strain(:),myUniqueValues);
```

The problem is that `myUniqueValues` is not "monotonically non-decreasing." This example produces the same error:

```
n  = hist(randi(3,[1 10]),[3 2 1]);
```

which results in

```
Error using histc
Edge vector must be monotonically non-decreasing.

Error in hist (line 92)
    nn = histc(y,edges,1);
```

I'm not sure what this is happening as `unique` is supposed to sort it's output. So I can't replicate your error exactly in R2013b. Perhaps you're running an older version of Matlab. I'd look at what the value of `myUniqueValues` is.

Answer (score 0):

This type of errors is mainly due to the second argument of `hist` function not being monotonically non-decreasing

Answer (score 0):

Change your `unique` line to:

```
myUniqueValues = unique(roundedValues,'sorted');
```

You probably have an old version that does not sort by default, but rather uses "stable" ordering.

Comment: The current documentation seems to indicate that this changed behavior is only for the multiple output cases, but perhaps not. I couldn't find a way to replicate the error in 2013b using the `'legacy'` option either.

Comment: @chappjc `Unique` always sorted outputs. Only now, they have included an option as `'stable'`.  Am I correct?

Comment: @Parag Honestly, I couldn't tell you.  I think horchler is right that legacy only applies to the indexes, but then I don't have any way to check only versions.